# Stumped on a Bayes Theorem Question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A certain medical syndrome is usually associated with two overlapping sets of symptoms, A and B. Suppose it is known that:

P($A|B$) = 0.8

P($B|A$) = 0.9

P($B'|A'$) = 0.85

Find P($A'$|$B'$)

From the algebra I have done, it seems that there is missing information. Can anyone solve this or corroborate my suspicion?

Comment: What is the ${}^C$ supposed to mean?

Comment: The compliment of the Event.

Comment: Changed it to prime if that helps

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$ P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}, $$
and vice versa, so
$$ P(A \cap B) = 0.8 P(B) = 0.9 P(A). $$
On the other hand,
$$ P(B' \mid A') = \frac{P(A' \cap B')}{1-P(A)} = \frac{1-P(A \cup B)}{1-P(A)}, $$
and $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$
So
$$ 1+P(A \cap B) -P(A)-P(B) = 0.85(1-P(A)) $$
We now have 3 equations in 3 unknowns, so they should be solvable for $P(A),P(B),P(A\cap B)$. Indeed, they solve to
$$ P(A) = 2/5 \\
P(B) = 9/20 \\
P(A \cap B) = 9/25
 $$
Now we can just use
$$ P(A' \mid B') = \frac{1-P(A)}{1-P(B)}P(B' \mid A') = \frac{3/5}{11/20}\frac{17}{20} = \frac{51}{55} $$

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Senor